# Search function Laravel 5.8 not working for plural words

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I currently have a search function in my application that works just fine but I want it to return a broader search. Let me explain.

I have a recipe application where each user can upload a recipe. In the search bar, you can search for recipes and that returns a result based on what is in the database. My problem is, if you search for something in plural, or misspell a little bit, there is no output. Example: search for smoothies (plural) when the recipes are titled smoothie (singular). However, if you search for a recipe and the word is incomplete (smooth, smo, sm) then it returns all the results that have the completed word. So I want that same functionality, but for words that have too many letters or are in plural.

Here is my current logic:

```
public function search(Request $request){
        $q = $request->input('search');
        $recipes = Recipe::where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$q.'%')->orWhere('description', 'LIKE', '%'.$q.'%')->get();
        return view('recipes.results')->with('recipes', $recipes)->with('query', $q);
```

The function searches through titles and descriptions of recipes.

I appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: for the plural words i think ('title', 'LIKE', $q.'%') would work but for misspell search i think you need to look at laravel scout and a driver like algolia / elastic search / or a free driver like TNT search scout driver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let me rephrase your code. And Try to read this helpful helper of laravel[Laravel Helpers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-str-plural)

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
//dont forget to import this


public function search(Request $request){

    $q = $request->input('search');
    $singular = Str::singular($q);
    $plural= Str::plural($q);

    $recipes = Recipe::where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$singular .'%')
       ->orWhere('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$plural.'%')
       ->orWhere('description', 'LIKE', '%'.$singular .'%')
       ->orWhere('description', 'LIKE', '%'.$plural.'%')
       ->get();

    return view('recipes.results')->with('recipes', $recipes)->with('query', $q);
```

Comment: how about the mispelled ?

Answer (score 0):

this will work but i don't think this is the right way to do that

```
public function search(Request $request){
    $q = $request->input('search');
    $recipes = Recipe::where(function($query) use($q){
        for($x = 3; $x < strlen($q); $x++) {
            if($x==3) {
                $query->where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.substr($q, 0, $x).'%');
            }
            else {
                $query->orWhere('title', 'LIKE', '%'.substr($q, 0, $x).'%');
            }
        }
    })->orWhere('description', 'LIKE', '%'.$q.'%')->get();
    return view('recipes.results')->with('recipes', $recipes)->with('query', $q);
```

when the user search for "smoothies" it will search all recipes with

smo, smoo, smoot, smooth, smoothi, smoothie, smoothies